# Implementation of gui designer

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, designer

I'm interested in making my own small gui designer for learning purposes in Qt. Just basic drag and drop from left panel which would have controls, to right panel on which they could be selected, moved, resized and have their properties changed (name and such) and eventually (if selected) be lined up.

I would use QGraphicsScene as the right panel cause it already has selecting and moving implemented. But how would I implement resizing? And then how would I generate a QWidget class with controls at same positions? Or is there an easier way?

What would be the best way to implement all of this? All suggestions are welcome and keep in mind that it won't be complex as Qt designer.

Comment: This is an extremely non-trivial application "for learning purposes in Qt".

Comment: It's not my first time using Qt or c++, it's meant as in "perfecting" my knowledge in Qt and learning THIS in particular, therefore - learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some widgets, which are going to be dragged from the left panel -maybe a tree view with icons- and dropped to the scene.

These widgets should inherit from `QGraphicsWidget`. You can also inherit `QWidget` and put the widgets into scene via `QGraphicsProxyWidget`. They can be resized by highlighting corners and overloading the mouse events. Please check out [corner grabbers](http://www.davidwdrell.net/wordpress/?page_id=46) and [sizable box](http://www.davidwdrell.net/wordpress/?page_id=106) examples. Also check out `QSizeGrip`. It is the resizing grip of any `QStatusBar`.

Property panel is the easiest, you should list the properties of the clicked item. To line up, you can reinvent the wheel and write a *layout maker* class, or simply use `QGraphicsLayout` and highlight the layout on your interface. Ctrl+left click should select multiple widgets, a layout button should layout them programmatically, and a bounding rectangle item should be drawn.

Comment: I already made a widget with control icons which can be dragged and dropped to the `QGraphicsScene`. These controls inherit `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and later their positions and sizes will determine real control positions and sizes on another `QWidget`. The only problem I have here is making these controls resizable. If I now switch to custom `QGraphicsWidget`, how can I make them paint regular controls (`QPushButtons` etc)?

Comment: Did you take a look at QGraphicsProxyWidget usage?

Comment: Yes I did, but these widgets aren't movable and selectable when on `QGraphicsScene`, they respond to mouse events like normal widgets do.

Comment: OK, then stick to graphicswidget and utilize the painter device to draw your stuff. Since it inherits QGraphicsItem, you can overload the paint method. Example here http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?index=507&key=CustomQGraphicsWidget